# Can get background on animation to turn white and cover other image

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I am writing an overlay effect for a employee page that will show the employee's photos then when you click on the photo the text expands to the right and a quote slides down from under neath the photo. If the photo is not first then the photo will slide to the left of the page and the text will slide to the right out from under the photo. I can't seem to get the background color of the overlay to show up? I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If someone could take a look and let me know I would much appreciate it.

Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/BrentRansom/FLUPD/1/

**CSS**

```
#expand .bio-pic2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#expand {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    width: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.bio-pic2 img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 323px;
}

.testimonial {
    position: absolute;
    top: 333px;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.desc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 333px;
}

.bio-pic {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9998;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="expand">
        <div class="bio-pic">
            <img src="http://www.brent-ransom.com/photo-img.jpg" />
            <div class="bio-nt">
                <h2>Name</h2>
                <h3>Position</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="testimonial">
               A testimonial!
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="desc">
        This is a paragraph of text.
    </div>
    <div class="bio-pic">
        <img src="http://www.brent-ransom.com/photo-img.jpg" />
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(".bio-pic").click(function() {
     $('.bio-pic2').toggle("slow");

    var menu = $("#expand")
    if ($(menu).is(":visible")) {
        $(menu).animate({width: 0}, 1000, function() {$(menu).hide();});
    } else {
        $(menu).show().animate({width: 500}, 1000);           
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6dvqu/

Comment: I shall post this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely clear on what you are trying to do, but is it something similar to this?

First of all add a height to your `#expand` div which you want to display as an overlay, it is displaying without any height currently.

```
#expand {
    position:absolute;
    width:1000px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    z-index:9999;
   height:323px;
}
```

When your overlay is active, since it has z-index higher than your actual photo divs, you cannot click on it again to reset the overlay, instead you can bind the click event on the overlay itself.

```
$(".bio-pic").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //$('.bio-pic2').toggle("slow");
    var menu = $("#expand");
    $(menu).show().animate({
        width: 500
    }, 1000);
});
$("#expand").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: 0
    }, 1000, function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h64CZ/)**

Comment: Everything works great with this accept for one thing when I click on the second photo to have it expand out the first photo shows up on the overlay instead of the second photo. I have edited the file in here so show the second photo [link](http://jsfiddle.net)/BrentRansom/h64CZ/1/)